# How to compare the performance of Evolutionary Algorithms

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, optimization, mean, evolutionary-algorithms

I need to compare the performance of 3 Evolutionary algorithms on some Benchmark functions.

> Evolutionary algorithms are a heuristic-based approach which are used to solve optimization problems.

I have collected their best optimum value on different benchmark functions for multiple independent runs and calculated their mean and standard deviation. Would this be  suffice or I need to use some statistical tests like t-test to present some robust comparison.

> Note: I have only collected the final best value of each algorithms not all values during different iterations

Thank you

Comment: Hi there and welcome. Some comments. 1) Could you elaborate a little on how your EAs are different? 2) Is it possible for you to re-run the simulations? Because I do *not* believe collecting only the final optima is enough for a fair comparison. At the very least you'll need the starting values.

Comment: @Jim Hello, All 3 EAs are different